# How does an outsider get "citizenship" in one of the Five Great Shinobi Countries?

Tags: naruto

After re-watching *Naruto: Shippuden* with Kushina's history, I've noticed that on [her wiki page](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kushina_Uzumaki#Background) that

> At a young age she was sent to Konoha and enrolled in the Academy.

I'm aware of the connection the Uzumaki has with the village. However, without being born into their respected village other than the academy or married to one of the citizen (like Temari), how does one get a headband of one of the Five Shinobi Countries?

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! I noticed you have taken a [tour], which is great! I did some editing to improve the post and also removing some "fluffs" that aren't necesserarily needed in the post, I hope you can understand that. If my edit changed your intent, feel free to [edit] and/or rollback it. Finally, we hope you can enjoy and participate further in this site :)

Comment: Thank you! And no, I'm grateful for the edit! <3 I was just so into the question that I added unnecessary details XD.

Answer (score 1):

Kushina was an exception since she didn't move to the village but was sent there to become the next nine tails jinchūriki.

But I guess that if someone decided to move to another the village he would need to talk to the Kage and be accepted.

Comment: Could you provide the sources/references for the answer?